# How to plot a radial cutoff functions

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, mathematica

I want to plot the smooth positive radial cutoff function $\chi_2$ defined by
$$
\chi_2(x,y) =1 \qquad(100|x-y| \le |y|),
$$
$$
\chi_2(x,y)=0 \qquad(|y|\le 50|x-y|)
$$
and also the function $\chi_1 = 1 - \chi_2$.
I hope that I can plot this in mathematica, but it seems too hard for me.

Comment: What is the domain? For $(x,y)=(0,0)$ there hold $100|x-y|=0\leq 0=|y|$ and $|y|=0\leq 0=50|x-y|$ and gives a contradition in you definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is neither welldefined for $(x,y)=(0,0)$ nor defined for all $(x,y)$. For instance for $(x,y)=(5151,5075)$ you get
$$
100|x-y|=100\cdot76=7600>5075=|y|
$$
and
$$
|y|=5075>3800=50\cdot76=50|x-y|
$$